# Implement and run post-install script for unlocked sfdx package

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx

The title basically says it all: I am using SFDX (Unlocked packages) and I am looking for the same functionality that [ISVs have to run apex code post-install](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/apex_post_install_script_create.htm) after a package was installed.

I did not find anything equal for SFDX and I feel a little bit uncomfortable executing anonymous apex after a successfull install (however, this would be my current take). Any thoughts?

Comment: Making an [Rest API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/AsyncApexJob) call to run Apex code would be an option. A [git hook](https://githooks.com/), [TravisCI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/), or [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/deployment-integrations/) would be able to do this.

Comment: Whether the hook to run the apex post-install script is baked into the architecture of the org, or it is initiated via an API call as anonymous Apex, is there any difference? What is the discomfort running anonymous apex from?

Comment: I would say that the difference is that in one case the Salesforce infrastructure runs the "script" Apex as part of the installation process whilst in the other case there is a need to perform a post-installation step and manually request execution of the Apex - there's no guarantee that step is performed. There's also the difference in contextual user.

Answer (score 3):

If we're talking about a full like-for-like functionality, I believe it's not really possible to mimic, see [these docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/apex_post_install_script.htm):

> The post install script is invoked after tests have been run, and is subject to default governor limits. It runs as a special system user that represents your package, so all operations performed by the script appear to be done by your package. You can access this user by using UserInfo. You will only see this user at runtime, not while running tests.

> If the script fails, the install/upgrade is aborted. Any errors in the script are emailed to the user specified in the Notify on Apex Error field of the package. If no user is specified, the install/upgrade details will be unavailable.

So basically the post-install script is embedded in the installation of the package itself and if it fails the installation process as a whole is aborted. This really protects you from ending up in an intermediate state of successfully installing a package while failing to execute a post-install script.

We have a (naive) implementation of a post-install script for one of our unlocked packages, it is hooked in our SFDX plugin for releases and it is executed upon successfully installing a package version in an org.

1. We have a `post-install` folder in our SFDX project at the same level of `force-app` and it contains the metadata that should be deployed after installing a package version
2. Execute `sfdx force:source:deploy -p "post-install" -u <username> -l RunLocalTests --json`

So, this works in the sense that this is executed right after installing a package version but it is naive in the sense that there is absolutely no guarantee that this will work and since it's a separate process from installing the package version in the org, one can end up in inconsistent states.