# Triggering Scheduled Job During Unlocked Package Installation/Upgrade

Tags: scheduled-apex, unlocked-package, scheduled-job, postinstall

Within our unlocked package, we have implemented a class TimesheetWindowScheduler that implements the Schedulable interface. This class is responsible for executing specific tasks.

```
public with sharing class TimesheetWindowScheduler implements Schedulable {
    public void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
       //... do something
    }
```

Ideally, we aim to trigger the scheduling of this job automatically upon the installation or upgrade of our package

```
TimesheetWindowScheduler m = new TimesheetWindowScheduler();
System.schedule(TIMESHEET_WINDOW_SCHEDULER, schedule, m);
```

Without open developer console, do we have any other way to do that?

Comment: This might be helpful resource - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32607/installhandler-runs-under-a-special-ghost-user-what-rights-does-it-have

Comment: ah, InstallHandler for managed package, but I'd like run on `unlocked` package

Comment: ouch, my mistake, I apologise  for the inconvenience. In case of unlocked package -- this might help - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/236826/implement-and-run-post-install-script-for-unlocked-sfdx-package

Comment: ah no, it's okay. but in my case, I need to run to trigger Apex Scheduler. But It can't able to access Package's Class from `sfdx force:source:deploy`

Comment: Navigate to Salesforce Setup.
Search for "Apex Classes" and select it.
Here you should find a button or link to "Schedule Apex."
You can then select your TimesheetWindowScheduler class and set the frequency, start date, end date, and preferred start time.

Comment: Ah yeah, But I'd like to do that via code, do we have any way to do that?

Comment: You can run anonymous apex through the sf/sfdx CLI, so the two lines you have could be sent for anonymous execution by a second CLI command in your "install script". Remember to include any namespace, if you have namespaced the unlocked package.

Comment: I'm trying to exec those 2 lines via `sf apex run` (with or without namespace) it always returns `Invalid type: TimesheetWindowScheduler` so I'm wondering does `org` can access package's apex class?